# coq Error: Cannot find library abstract_algebra in loadpath

Tags: coq

I am testing one of the `contrib` libraries of coq called corn: https://github.com/c-corn/corn

But I can't get the files to pass compilation. According to the README file, the package compiles with coq-8.4pl4. But when I tested that version, I got an error message:

```
...
coqc algebra\RSetoid -R . CoRN
File "d:\temp\corn/algebra\RSetoid.v", line 26, characters 0-32:
Error: Cannot find library abstract_algebra in loadpath
```

I also tried the latest 8.4 version (8.4pl6) and 8.5 beta 2, and got similar errors. The problem line itself reads:

```
Require Import abstract_algebra.
```

I am not familiar with this library (`abstract_algebra`). Does anyone know about this library, where to get it, or how to fix this error?

(I googled around the error message, and there was no mention of the `abstract_algebra` library).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it the contributed `MathClasses.interfaces.abstract_algebra` ? You can download user contributions from the Coq website.

Comment: https://coq.inria.fr/cocorico/MathClasses

Comment: @larsr Thanks. I'm looking to install MathClasses, but I met a problem installing MathClasses. I've asked a question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313458/