# how to install coq contribs using git?

Tags: git, coq

I am trying to install one of the coq user contrib libraries (MathClasses). After some googling, I found what seems to be a central git repository at the Coq website, https://gforge.inria.fr/git/coq-contribs/.

Following the [`README`](https://gforge.inria.fr/git/coq-contribs/00README) file there, I tried to get the source code by:

```
git clone git+ssh://scm.gforge.inria.fr/git/coq-contribs/coq-contribs.git
```

But I get an error:

```
Cloning into 'coq-contribs'...
ssh: connect to host gforge.inria.fr port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I tried this from both MinGW and Lubuntu 14.04, and got the same error.

My questions are:

1. How to fix the above error?
2. Is https://gforge.inria.fr/git/coq-contribs/ the right place to download user-contributed libraries? I tried `opam` on Lubuntu 14.04, but it seems to be linux only, and the stock version is lower (1.1.1) than recommended by what's suggested on the Coq website (1.2+).

Comment: The `git+shh` protocol in the URL looks funny to me, but I don't know anything about Inria.

Comment: There is also a github repo. https://github.com/math-classes/math-classes

Comment: I would just guess that nobody has updated the `README` in a while. Have you tried just feeding an https-based URL to git, same as what can be browsed? git works fine through http, just a little less efficiently.

Comment: @Atsby I tried to browse the source via the web, but there isn't an interface like those of github, where you can download a zip file. I've also tried: `git clone https://gforge.inria.fr/git/coq-contribs/coq-contribs.git`. It didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL `git+ssh://...` is probably for developers who need to be able to check in code.  You could use `git clone https://gforge.inria.fr/git/coq-contribs/math-classes.git` instead, but it is less recently updated than the github repo.

Or, you can download it from the official page:
http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/pylons/contribs/files/MathClasses/v8.4/MathClasses.interfaces.abstract_algebra.html

To compile, I did

```
git clone https://github.com/math-classes/math-classes.git
cd math-classes
./configure.sh
make -j
make install
```

Testing that it worked:

```
cd ..
coqtop
Require Import abstract_algebra.
```

Comment: Thanks. This works as advertised under Ubuntu 14.04. But it does not seem to work for Windows with MinGW/MSys. git clones fine, but the make generates a ton of errors. Any pointers on Windows platform?

Comment: Do you use case-sensitive file system? If not, that would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To install Coq contributions, you can now use the OPAM package manager. See for example [the list of OPAM packages for Coq](http://coq.io/opam/).